# Multiple joins in Yii2

Tags: yii2

In this case - 
Table 'districts' has two columns - id,district.
Table 'parties' have column - parties_partyname,parties_district

```
parties.parties_partyname = districts.district
```

Another table 'bills' has column partyname, billamount.

```
bills.partyname = parties.parties_partyname
```

Now what I want is to see the billamount for each district like below -

```
District    Sale
A   10000
B   20000
C   10000
D   20000
```

My search query is -

```
$query = Districts::find();
        $subquery = Bills::find()->select('parties_district,bills_partyname, billdate, sum(billamount) as sale')->groupBy(['parties_district']);
        $subquery->joinWith(['parties']);
        $query->leftJoin(['T' => $subquery], 'T.parties_district = districts.district');
```

I'm getting "(Not Set)" in the sale column. Please tell me what changes need to be done.
 Also I've tried to break in parts like this in partiesSearch model -

```
$query = Parties::find();
        $subquery = Bills::find()->select('bills_partyname, billdate, sum(billamount) as sale')->groupBy(['bills_partyname']);
        $query->leftJoin(['T' => $subquery], 'T.bills_partyname = parties_partyname');
```

still I'm getting not set as sale column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this question by - 'findbysql'. [Getting (not set) when joining a column which has a sum function in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028572/getting-not-set-when-joining-a-column-which-has-a-sum-function-in-yii2/37033502#37033502) - This link is helpful for this question.