# Getting (not set) when joining a column which has a sum function in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have two tables - parties, bills. In parties table the fiels are parties_partyname,parties_district. And in the bills table it has field bills_partyname, billamount,billdate.
I want to see the query as

```
SELECT parties_district,parties_partyname, COALESCE(sum(bills.billamount),0) as sale FROM `parties` left join bills on parties.parties_partyname = bills.bills_partyname group by parties.parties_partyname
```

My Search Model looks like -

```
$query = Parties::find()
        ->select('parties.parties_district, parties.parties_partyname, bills.billamount as sale')
        ->from('parties')
        ->leftJoin('bills',['bills.bills_partyname' => 'parties.parties_partyname'])
        ->groupBy('parties.parties_partyname');
```

Parties index.php

```
'parties_partyname',
        'parties_district',

    [
      'attribute' => 'sale',
      'value' => 'sale'
    ],
```

I've added `public $sale` in the parties model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use the activeQuery like you shown  you should use

```
$query = Parties::find()
    ->select('parties.parties_district as parties_district, 
         parties.parties_partyname as parties_partyname, 
         COALESCE(sum(bills.billamount),0) as sale ')
    ->from('parties')
    ->leftJoin('bills',['bills.bills_partyname' => 'parties.parties_partyname'])
    ->groupBy('parties.parties_partyname');
```

otherwise you can use a simple  (activeRecord) findBySql()  (this give you the query for dataProvider)

```
    $sql = 'SELECT 
                parties.parties_district as parties_district, 
                parties.parties_partyname as parties_partyname, 
                COALESCE(sum(bills.billamount),0) as sale 
            FROM `parties` 
            left join bills on parties.parties_partyname = bills.bills_partyname 
            group by parties.parties_partyname'
    $query = Parties::findBySql($sql);
```

if you use instead

```
    $models = Parties::findBySql($sql)>all();
```

you get all the models

for grid view if you value is the same of the attribute value use

```
    'parties_partyname',
    'parties_district',
    'sale',
```

without value =>

Comment: I'm using the activeQuery but getting 'not set' in the sale column in output.

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: and using findBySql ?

Comment: I'm not so sure how to use it.